# No LoginModules configured for DefaultPrincipalMapping WAS Libert y profile 8.5.5.9

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty, jaas

I used the info in this link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dev_prog_login_auth_data.html As per my info which I got from this discussion thread. https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/261209/websphere-liberty-profile-and-j2c-authdata-retriev-1.html

The DefaultPrincipalMapping programmatic login is avaiable and should work. I configured everything updated to Liberty profile v 8.5.5.9 , yet my code throws exception at [err] javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for DefaultPrincipalMapping [err] at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:264) [err] at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.(LoginContext.java:417) Here is my code snippet..

```
     Context context = new InitialContext();
     String user = (String) context.lookup("cell/persistent/ADBindUser");
     String password = (String) context.lookup("cell/persistent/ADBindPwd");

     Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     map.put(Constants.MAPPING_ALIAS, "WPSBIND");
```

// CallbackHandler callbackHandler = // WSMappingCallbackHandlerFactory.getInstance().getCallbackHandler(map, null);

```
     CallbackHandler callbackHandler =new WSMappingCallbackHandler(map, null);

     LoginContext loginContext = 
         new LoginContext("DefaultPrincipalMapping", callbackHandler);
     try{
         loginContext.login();
     }catch(LoginException le) {

     }
```

Can any one please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you add your `server.xml`? Did you added the `passwordUtilities-1.0` feature?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `"DefaultPrincipalMapping"` the login configuration `"system.DEFAULT"` did the job for me.
The final hint was hidden in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_authentication.html):

> `system.DEFAULT`
>
> Used for login when no JAAS configuration is specified.
>
> ...
>
> The system.WEB_INBOUND and system.DEFAULT configurations have these
>   default login modules in this order: **hashtable, userNameAndPassword,
>   certificate**, and **token**. The WSLogin configuration has the [proxy login module](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_authentication.html?view=kc#cwlp_authentication__proxy_login)
>   as the default login module, and the proxy delegates all the
>   operations to the real login module in system.DEFAULT.
>
> > `WSLogin` fails with an `Unrecognized Callback` in case the application uses e.g. `org.jboss.security.auth.callback.UsernamePasswordHandler` as the callback. If the application cannot be modified, `system.DEFAULT` provides an alternative.